# Boosting in solr vs lucene

Tags: solr, configuration

I am changing the search engine from `lucene` to `solr` , and i want to make config changes in my custom indexes , i am using the `search_keywords` field for the predictive search , and the field is also boosted in `lucene` ,

```
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="search_keywords" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
```

I want to know that how the same boosting will occur in `solr` , what changes i have to make?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can boost result at the time when you are getting result. Below are the code :

```
var filters = new HashSet<Expression<Func<ContentPageSearchModel, bool>>>();
var expression = BuildSearchExpression("searchtext");
filters.Add(expression);

Expression<Func<ContentPageSearchModel, bool>> BuildSearchExpression(string text)
        {
           var namePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContentPageSearchModel>();
            return namePredicate.Or(item => item.Name == text).Boost(3.0f);
        }
```